# что такое b в функции и как она получает

Tags: javascript

```js
function inBetween(a, b) {
  return function(x, b) {
    console.log(b);
    return x >= a && x <= b;
  };
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(arr.filter(inBetween(3, 6))); // 3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код возвращает на самом деле пустой массив. Это из-за того, что переменная `b` во внутренней функции затеняет переменную `b` во внешней. Во внешней функции переменная `b` означает максимальную границу выборки. А во внутренней функции она уже означает индекс массива ([подробнее об аргументах, которые получает функция, передаваемая в `filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)). Пустым массив получается потому, что индекс элемента в данном массиве из примера всегда получается меньше значения элемента, поэтому проверка `x <= b` всегда возвращает `false`.

Исправить можно так:

```js
function inBetween(min, max) { // min в данном примере = 3, а max = 6
  return function(x, b) { // x тут будет = элементу массива, а b = индексу
    console.log(b);
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  };
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(arr.filter(inBetween(3, 6))); // 3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function inBetween(a, b) {
  return function(x, b) {
    console.log(b);
    return x >= a && x <= b;
  };
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(arr.filter(inBetween(3, 6))); // (*)
```

**(*)** Вызов `inBetween(3, 6)` создает замыкание (a = 3, b = 6), возвращает новую функцию, которая помнит эти значения и отправляется в `filter()`.

Фильтр вызывает эту функцию для каждого элемента, и передает ей три аргумента,
`(значение_элемента, номер_элемента, ссылка_на_массив)`

Соответственно, `x` получает значения элементов, `b` - их номера. И это внутреннее `b` не имеет никакого отношения к внешнему `b` из замыкания (и вовсе не нужен там).

```js
function inBetween(a, b) {
  return function(x, index) {
    console.log(index);
    return a <= x && x <= b; // Сравнение с внешними `a` и `b`
  };
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log(arr.filter(inBetween(3, 6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

b является параметром в этой функции.